# С++ Microsoft MFC TreeView Icons

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, treeview, icons

I have written a code of the TreeView Control by a blog article. I am trying to add  icons to list items. But icons are no rendered.
I have a next code:

```
void CLeftView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    CTreeView::OnInitialUpdate();

    // TODO: Add items by GetTreeCtrl().

    HICON hi = NULL;
    hi = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
    if (hi != NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"resource1");
    }
    else MessageBox(NULL, L"Not resource1");
    HICON lo = NULL;
    lo = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON2));
    if (lo != NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"resource2");
    }
    else MessageBox(NULL, L"Not resource2");

    CImageList m_tree_imglist;
    CTreeCtrl & tc = CTreeView::GetTreeCtrl();

    m_tree_imglist.Create(16, 16, ILC_COLOR32 | ILC_MASK, 0, 2);

    m_tree_imglist.Add(hi);
    m_tree_imglist.Add(lo);


    tc.SetImageList(&m_tree_imglist, TVSIL_NORMAL);

    HTREEITEM hItem;
    hItem = tc.InsertItem(L"Fonts", 0, 0, TVI_ROOT);
    tc.InsertItem(L"Arial", 0, 0, hItem);
    tc.InsertItem(L"Times", 0, 0, hItem);
    tc.Expand(hItem, TVE_EXPAND);
}
```

Icons have added to resource's files. There's do I have a bug? I have message boxes with a next text: "resource1", "resource2".

Comment: For a dirty and fast solution, detach your local variable m_treee_imgList.Detach() before the funtion ends. However a better an right solution is to declare the variable m_treee_imgList as class member as Barmak shows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`m_tree_imglist` is declared on stack, this image list is destroyed after `OnInitialUpdate` exits, so `CTreeCtrl` no longer has an image list.

Image list should be declared as class member instead, so that it remains valid as long as `CTreeCtrl` needs it. Note the `m_` prefix is usually used in MFC to indicate "class member".

```
class CLeftView : public CTreeView
{
    CImageList m_tree_imglist;
    ...
};

void CLeftView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    ...
    //CImageList m_tree_imglist; <- remove
    tc.SetImageList(&m_tree_imglist, TVSIL_NORMAL);
}
```